# What's the meaning of "C'est le sancho" ?

Tags: sens, traduction, vocabulaire, expressions-idiomatiques, demande-de-mot

What's the meaning of "C'est le sancho"?

I want to know the meaning of this French expression.

Comment: When asking for the meaning of an expression, please provide some context. As  ﺪﺪﺪ 
 commented, both *c'est le Sancho* (rare, colloquial) and *c'est le sang chaud* are possible.

Answer (score 4):

It's an expression from Marseille. It's like saying my brother, my dude, my man. For example, to say "this guy is a really good friend" you can say "lui c'est le sancho".

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Cette expression n'existe pas.

Je pense qu'il s'agit de : « Avoir le sang chaud », qui signifie « s’emporter facilement. »

Answer (score 0):

Without any context, here my two cents (not native speaker). It may refer to the football player

> Jadon Malik Sancho. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jadon_Sancho

It may also refer to Sancho Pança (from Don Quichotte).

But it would be "C'est Sancho' without the definite article.